# FileNotFoundError Selenium Stealth Python

Tags: python, selenium, pyinstaller

I am running selenium-stealth in Python 3.9.3 on MacOS.

When I build to an app using PyInstaller (
`pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --hidden-import "cmath"  "/Users/name/Downloads/AmazonSellerCentral/main.py"`) I get the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 141, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 77, in create_driver
  File "selenium_stealth/__init__.py", line 45, in stealth
  File "selenium_stealth/utils.py", line 8, in with_utils
  File "pathlib.py", line 1255, in read_text
  File "pathlib.py", line 1241, in open
  File "pathlib.py", line 1109, in _opener
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/7z/3spcsmdx5n344dh0fb5j0hl40000gn/T/_MEIqfmicz/selenium_stealth/js/utils.js'
```

.

However, simply running `python3 main.py` works fine.

Reinstalling selenium-stealth did nothing, I'm unsure what I can try to fix/change from here?

Answer (score 2):

**quick turnaround** (for issue pls refer to my comment in comments section):
step 1: build the package , refer the command in code section) 
step 2: create folder --> dist\your package(in my case slhpackage)\selenium_stealth\js 
step 3- copy the js files from https://github.com/diprajpatra/selenium-stealth/tree/main/selenium_stealth/js and put it in folder created in step 2.

and now your executable should run fine.

```
pyinstaller slhpackage.py # build package (1)
```

```
#Python version ==> Python: 3.9.2 (conda)
```

Comment: Still the same issue, I don't think it can be my code since it works fine on WIndows, runs fine as a .py file on Windows and Mac, possibly is an issue with 3.9.3.

Comment: sorry about that. I tried on 3.9.2 and all worked well too. fyip.. i am on mac 10.15.7(macOS Catalina)

Comment: i think found the issue, but would need time to investigate further.

Comment: i think , i have found the issue, but would need time to investigate further. refer "https://github.com/diprajpatra/selenium-stealth/blob/main/selenium_stealth/utils.py" , for js folder it picks using Path(__file__).parent.joinpath("js/utils.js").read_text() , the __file__ is changed by pyinstaller. second issue is pyinstaller does not put the js folder which need to be placed explicitly.  one way is clone and contribute to  selenium-stealth or explore options in pyinstaller if __file__ can be overwritten. Once I have time will chk if I can fix this. Once get a fix, will update the answer. thx

Comment: Agreed this would most likely work, I haven't tested it, but it doesn't really solve in an ideal way, perhaps it means editing selenium-stealth source code which is far from ideal

Comment: changing source code and sending merge request, means contributing to open source :) community! hey there, pls accept the answer if it helped. Thanks

Comment: Not sure if I know enough to fully rewrite it, I was thinking more just editing my pyinstaller files to match my situation! I’ve upvoted your answer but I’m still hoping to get something a bit better so I can just build the app and no extra files.

Answer (score 2):

I used Python 3.9 and encountered the same issue today. As @simpleApp said, I followed the same with least number of modifications and it works for me as of now.

#### Follow below given steps:

- Make sure you that you  copy all the files from this [***link***](https://github.com/diprajpatra/selenium-stealth/tree/main/selenium_stealth/js).
- Paste all the files in `folder_name(might be anthing you wish)/selenium_stealth/js`.
  [Make sure you that you keep the names **selenium_stealth/js** with no modifications at any cost, else you'll face conflicts.]
- Then run the executable command with the folder_name added.

For convenience, I'm adding it here so that it'd be easier not only for you, but for everyone who uses it.

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --icon "dir:\path\to\icon.ico" --add-data "dir:\path\to\folder_name\mentioned\above;." --add-binary "dir:/path/to/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe;./selenium/webdriver" "dir:/path/to/your/python/file.py"
```

Copy the code, modify it based on your file paths (I've given generic names).
I'd recommend you to make a `.bat` file for paste the code in it for future use.

Here's the snippet of my code:

```
@ECHO OFF
color 09
echo Immediate direct Conversion of .py to .exe standalone by PiXinCreate
echo.
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --icon "dir:\path\to\icon.ico" --add-data "dir:\path\to\folder_name\mentioned\above;." --add-binary "dir:/path/to/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe;./selenium/webdriver" "dir:/path/to/your/python/file.py"
echo.
echo .exe has been successfully created for .py 
echo.
pause.
exit
```

- My code actually creates a onefile, which is standalone executable, in the terminal window.
- You can remove the icon part if not needed.
  Feel free to revert back if anything goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you're getting indicates that maybe something is wrong with the path of the file.

Make sure that the file `utils.js` exists at the path where it's trying to be located.

If not you could try to download it externally and placing it inside that path. I don't think that would be a good recommendation though.

Comment: It is definitely in the path, and works fine when running as a .py file just not as an app in the same path

Answer (score 0):

first remove `--onefile` from the command and build the app, after building you would find selenium-stealth folder inside of the folder that apeared after build,put [this](https://github.com/diprajpatra/selenium-stealth/tree/main/selenium_stealth/js) folder(js) inside of selenium-stealth and run the app.
i was looking for solution and it worked for me.